# Run sql scripts in numeric order

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a cmd script which creates a database and runs scripts in a folder. I have an issue when i have scripts 1 to 100 - it doesn't run them sequentially. It seems to run 1-10 and then 100 and then 11 onwards. How can I get it to run the scripts in numeric order?

```
for %%F IN (%currentdir%\MyScripts\*) do (
@echo %%F
%sqlRunner% -S %dbServer%  -U %username% -P %password% -d %dbName% -i %%F -b
if ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ERROR)
```

Comment: Rename the scripts so the numbers are zero padded:  "script001" instead of "script1".

Comment: It is running them sequentially, but it is sorting in string/alphabetic order (all the 1's - 1, 10, 100 - all the 2's - 2, 20, 200 - all the 3's) instead of numerical order (1, 2, 3 ... 10, 11, 12...). @GordonLinoff's suggestion of padded numbers makes string order and numeric order sort the same way by making them (all the 000's...).

Comment: The batch file can be written to launch the scripts numerically but the code would depend on the format of the script names.

Comment: Hmm...what if some of these scripts have been run on production and the script number is used to identify if it was run/not i.e its inserted into a version table.This number should ideally match the script name, so if i have to rename the script name to 00xx, I don't want to update all the records in the version table as well. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gordon just mentioned above you can solve your problem using zero padding. You are having it because your script is picking up the names in ascending order by starting with the smallest string first. In case of your script names:

```
script1 < script2 .... < script10 < script100 < script11 ... < script99  (just string comparison)
```

Which clearly shows why you are having the problem running the scripts in order.

But this problem can be fixed by zero padding as shown in the string order below:

```
script001 < script002 ... < script 010 ...< script050 ... < script100 (just string comparison)
```

Hence the scripts would now be executed in order.